# How to create UIPageViewController in IOS 5.0?

Tags: ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to IOS development and want to create UIPageViewController in IOS 5.Please Guide me!.thanks in advance

Comment: Without using Xib,to implement by code itself

Answer (score 0):

XCode -> File -> New.. Project -> iOS/Application -> Page-Based application.